# Finding library by header file

Tags: c, linux

I'd like to compile following simple `syslog` logging program:

```
#include <syslog.h>

setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_NOTICE));

openlog ("exampleprog", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);

syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "Program started by User %d", getuid ());
syslog (LOG_INFO, "A tree falls in a forest");

closelog ();
```

I know the location of `syslog.h` but how can i know the library name & location of syslog to tell the compiler to link to? Is there an universal way to find out the lib with definitions of header file declarations (for e.g. in what lib is the function x definition (body) declared in abc.h)?

Comment: [Read the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) (which doesn't mention a library)? For non-system functions, find and read its documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`syslog()` is defined in the C library, and your compiler will link against it by default. 
On my system, assuming your compiler is `gcc`, you can see the default compiler parameters invoked using `gcc -v file.c -o file.o`. Emphasis on the `-v` switch.

Calling `nm` on the C library gives:

```
nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep syslog
00000000000fffd0 T syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an universal way to find out the lib with definitions of header file declarations (for e.g. in what lib is the function x definition (body) declared in abc.h)?

Unfortunately, no, there isn't.  C doesn't require there to be any connection whatsoever between the name of a library and the name of its associated headers.

The most broadly applicable suggestion I can give you is "consult the documentation for the library", but even that doesn't always work.  Sorry.